# dSYM file when Archiving is missing debug info

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, dsym

I have a workspace with two project files in it. One contains my app code (APP), the other builds a static library (Pods) that is linked into the APP project.

The dSYM being generated when selecting `Product->Archive` contains only the debug info for the APP project. If I build by selecting `Product->Build For->Archiving/` Xcode generates a dSYM that contains all required debug info.

According to the following answer this was a bug in Xcode and is now fixed in version >=4.6.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368776/215748

I am using Xcode Version 4.6.2 (4H1003) and still have this problem.

**Is this really a bug in Xcode or is there a build setting that is causing this?**

I have looked into COPY_PHASE_STRIP, STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT, GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN and GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN already, which have no effect.

Comment: Getting this on Xcode 5.1.1...

Comment: I'm still getting this with Xcode 12.0.1 seven years after this question was asked. Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode 12.0.1 no longer contains `Product`->`Build For`->`Archiving`. No clue how I'm getting an archive that contains all debug symbols :-(